# Swift app creates empty files

Tags: swift, macos

I'm building a small app that sits in the toolbar, when a file or folder is dragged to it, it's uploaded to S3.  To speed up the process of uploading folders I tar and gzip them before uploading.  I have this working 100% on my computer however when others run the code or compiled app the tar.gz files are always 0 bytes.  I've also tried to use the SSZipArchive framework but also get 0 byte files.

```
let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
let uuidin = uuid.startIndex.advancedBy(6)
let suuid = uuid.substringToIndex(uuidin).lowercaseString
if CFURLHasDirectoryPath(fileURL) {
    let folder = fileURL.absoluteString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("file://", withString: "")

    shell("tar", "-C", folder, "-czf", suuid+".tar.gz", ".")

    //            _ = SSZipArchive.createZipFileAtPath(suuid+".zip", withContentsOfDirectory: folder)
    fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: suuid+".tar.gz")
    isFolder = true
}
```

Comment: Not related, but `fileURL.absoluteString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("file://", withString: "")` is exactly the same as `fileURL.path!`

Comment: It sounds like the sandbox is getting you. You may need to make sure that the folder you're working in is chosen with an NSOpenPanel first.

Comment: I guess the drag would take care of that, but it still sounds like an access/permissions issue

Comment: I know this is old, but I was just having a similar issue with `webView runOpenPanelForFileButtonWith WebOpenPanelResultListener` where it was uploading a file zero bytes in length.  And it wasn't file permissions.  Turns out that @vadian's comment above was the key to my solution!  With the "`file://`" part prepended, the upload would create the file server-side, but fail to actually find the file locally.  After getting `.path` to the `URL` instead of just using its string, plus `.removingPercentEncoding`, now my upload works perfectly.